# Unable to change the item text color and item icon tint

Tags: android, android-navigationview

Im trying to change the text color and icon tint color of navigation view as follows,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

        <include layout="@layout/include_list_viewpager"/>


        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NavigationView"
            app:itemTextAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:menu="@menu/drawer_view"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

But this doesnt helped me to change the color..So I tried setting the color programmatically as follows,

```
   // FOR NAVIGATION VIEW ITEM TEXT COLOR
        int[][] state = new int[][]{
                new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // disabled
                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
                new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}  // pressed

        };

        int[] color = new int[]{
                Color.WHITE,
                Color.WHITE,
                Color.WHITE,
                Color.WHITE
        };

        ColorStateList csl = new ColorStateList(state, color);


// FOR NAVIGATION VIEW ITEM ICON COLOR
        int[][] states = new int[][]{
                new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // disabled
                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_enabled}, // enabled
                new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // unchecked
                new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}  // pressed

        };

        int[] colors = new int[]{
                Color.WHITE,
                Color.WHITE,
                Color.WHITE,
                Color.WHITE
        };

        ColorStateList csl2 = new ColorStateList(states, colors);

        navigationView.setItemTextColor(csl);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(csl2);
```

Though I have tried setting the itemTextColor and itemIconTint to white programmatically as well as through xml, it is not effecting. Its still grey in color. How can I be able to sort this out?

**UPDATE:**

I have ofcourse tried setting the following theme to navigationview

```
<style name="AppTheme.NavigationView">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: You can use custom theme to change textcolor and icontint of navigationview

Comment: I have ofcourse tried it. I have updated  the question  with same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to use Custom [Color State](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) drawable for changing menu item's text and icon color.

```
 app:itemIconTint="@color/custom_text_color" //icon color
app:itemTextColor="@color/custom_text_color" //text color
app:itemBackground="@drawable/menu_background_color" //background
```

in **res/color/custom_text_color.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="@color/White" android:state_checked="true" />
  <item android:color="@color/Black" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Also in **res/drawable/menu_background_color.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"  android:state_checked="false"/>
  <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

Comment: still no effects... :(

Comment: are u programetically creating menu items?

Comment: No bro... Im using xml

Comment: Try change   android:state_checked to android:state_pressed.

Comment: why is this the accepted answer if you said it doesnt work?  what did you do?

Answer (score 0):

when i edit checkable in menu, it work.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_list"
            android:title="@string/list_title"
            android:checkable="true"
    />
    <item
            android:id="@+id/statistics"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_statistics"
            android:title="@string/statistics_title"
            android:checkable="true"/>
</menu>
```